# Should we rename the 'tri' tag to 'reference implementation'?

Tags: discussion, tags

I appreciate that there needs to be a tag for the Tridion Reference Implementation.

But I highly doubt that [tri](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tri) is the best tag name. If the product itself was named 'tri' that would be a great tag to use. But it's not: it is named Tridion Reference Implementation (when used outside of a Tridion context) or Reference Implementation (when the Tridion context has already been established).

Can we get rid of the [tri](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tri) tag and just use [reference-implementation](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-implementation)?

Comment: Bart apparently favors [tag:tri]: http://bkoopman.github.io/tri/

Answer (score 4):

Definitely not in favor of [tri](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tri), doesn't seem to make much sense unless you're aware of all the TLAs, like ST, XPM, FH, TCM, CD, TDS, AM (1 & 2), OE, SE, DCP, DCT, CID, TBB, UGC, etc.

BTW, it is named **SDL** Tridion Reference Implementation, since the product name is SDL Tridion.

Answer (score 4):

Fair point. Have actioned: [tri](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tri) is no more.

Comment: Thanks Rob. I was looking for  a "propose another name for this tag" button, but guess it either doesn't exist or I don't have sufficient rep for it.